# SQL Get UID when Group by

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I do a select from table

```
[V_RPT_BelegungKostenstelleDetail] 
WHERE SO_UID = '7C7035C8-56DD-4A44-93CC-F16FD66280A3' 
AND GB_UID = '4FF1B0EE-A5DD-4699-94B7-760922666CE2'
AND GS_UID = '1188759A-54E1-4323-8BF2-85E71B3C796E'
AND RM_UID = '088C3559-6E6E-468A-9554-6740840FCBA1'
AND NA_UID= '96A2A8DB-8C83-4C60-9060-F0F55719AF5C'
GROUP BY KST_UID
```

How can I get SO_UID? It is the same everywhere, but I get an error when I try to get SO_UID with the return values...

SO_UID is not necessarely given like '7C7035C8-56DD-4A44-93CC-F16FD66280A3' here, so I can't just add it manually as string.

Comment: Can you give more detail as what is in your select clause and a sample data of few rows in  V_RPT_BelegungKostenstelleDetail explaining how SO_UID will be repeated (Not sure if I'm understanding it right)?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use an [aggregate function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173454.aspx) to get other column data. As this column will always have the same value (thanks to the `WHERE` clause), you can use `MAX()`:

```
SELECT KST_UID, MAX(SO_UID) 
FROM [V_RPT_BelegungKostenstelleDetail] 
WHERE SO_UID = '7C7035C8-56DD-4A44-93CC-F16FD66280A3' 
AND GB_UID = '4FF1B0EE-A5DD-4699-94B7-760922666CE2'
AND GS_UID = '1188759A-54E1-4323-8BF2-85E71B3C796E'
AND RM_UID = '088C3559-6E6E-468A-9554-6740840FCBA1'
AND NA_UID= '96A2A8DB-8C83-4C60-9060-F0F55719AF5C'
GROUP BY KST_UID
```

Comment: Operand data-type uniqueidentifier is invalid for max-Operator

Comment: @Quandary - From MSDN: "MAX can be used with numeric, character, and datetime columns"

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is as simple as the question is stupid:

```
SELECT KST_UID, SO_UID, GB_UID, RM_UID, NA_UID
FROM [V_RPT_BelegungKostenstelleDetail] 

WHERE  SO_UID = '7C7035C8-56DD-4A44-93CC-F16FD66280A3' 
   AND GB_UID = '4FF1B0EE-A5DD-4699-94B7-760922666CE2'
   AND GS_UID = '1188759A-54E1-4323-8BF2-85E71B3C796E'
   AND RM_UID = '088C3559-6E6E-468A-9554-6740840FCBA1'
   AND NA_UID = '96A2A8DB-8C83-4C60-9060-F0F55719AF5C'
GROUP BY KST_UID, SO_UID, GB_UID, RM_UID, NA_UID
```